# Url changes as angular app loads on github pages

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, github-pages, angular-cli-ghpages

A weird behavior occurs as I try to access my angular website on github pages. The url changes once I open the page. Check it through this url. https://youssefsharief.github.io/youtube-trending-videos-per-country-app/

The expected url is https://youssefsharief.github.io/youtube-trending-videos-per-country-app/

This url is converted to https://youssefsharief.github.io/ as the page loads.
This app is scaffolded by angular-cli. Note that this is my build command

```
"build": "ng build --prod --base-href youtube-trending-videos-per-country-app --output-path docs"
```

Comment: Question in there someplace? What is the `expected` vs. `actual`? Or is this just click bait?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I updated the post to address your question

Answer (score 0):

It is weird that you "arrive" at site with one URL and continue to navigate the app with different URLs. Hopefully this answer will explain the *dynamic* nature of URLs on GitHub Sites.

This is not related to Angular - it is a web server (Jekyll) thing.

GitHub uses Jekyll to serve the content from your repository. GitHub uses the [Jekyll Relative Links Plugin](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-relative-links) to manage relative links on your site. This is done in order to deal with the various ways one can arrive at a URL at GitHub.

The following article explains how Jekyll works. Although it says nothing about Angular and refers to configuration `yaml` files. It should still clarify how your Angular app URLS are following these rules:

http://downtothewire.io/2015/08/15/configuring-jekyll-for-user-and-project-github-pages/

But you didn't provide any of this configuration, you just deployed your application in production mode. Right, so GitHub is rewriting your relative URLs on the fly based upon your `<base href>` attribute value automatically - and your site works as it should (except for that weird entry URL).

You can experiment with these rules by changing the `<base>` tag `href` attribute value, but note that a single slash "/" is frowned upon as being ambiguous to Jekyll.